# Getting validation message while trying to use sendKeys through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have written a simple code to enter email in facebook login page. But while entering the email value through sendKeys i am getting validation like "The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type By". I have already checked the compliance version which is 1.8. So what is going wrong here??. Below is code snippet:

```
package SeleniumTests;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class OpenFacebook {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver path");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']").sendKeys("swarup.wipro@gmail.com");

    }

}
```

I am getting an option of Add cast to By.xpath as a quick fix. Can somebody explain the usage of this or is there any other solution available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closing bracket is missing in your code before **.sendKeys**
Try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']")).sendKeys("swarup.wipro@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Thanks,it solved my problem. I hope i can get rid of silly mistakes like these next time.

Answer (score 1):

As @KoustubhMadkaikar and @AndiCover mentioned, though adding the necessary closing bracket i.e. **`)`** will solve the current issue but as per the best practices you should supply the `tagName` for your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) to be robust and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("swarup.wipro@gmail.com");
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#email")).sendKeys("swarup.wipro@gmail.com");
  ```

Comment: upvote for adding the CSS Selector which is a faster way to locate the element.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB for your suggestion.

Comment: @Swarup What? suggestion ... I thought that was a canonical answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB By Suggestion i meant the "tagName for your locator startegy" part. Anyway thanks a ton for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing round bracket `)`, use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']")).sendKeys("swarup.wipro@gmail.com");
```

Comment: You missed closing round bracket [ ) ]